# Merge or Union tables in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables that I would like to combine into an unduplicated list. I have a 'SUB' table that has a 1 column named 'ID' containing a unique identifier for 11,000 some records. I also have another table with 75,000 rows called 'MASTER'. It contains two columns, 'ID' which has the same unique identifier and 'CODE' which contains a unique code for each ID. I want to create a new table that has the 11,000 IDs from the 'SUB' table with the corresponding 'CODE's that match the 'SUB' IDs from the 'MASTER' table. I have used a basic UNION Query, but the results had duplication in the 'ID' column. I tried to consolidate the table produced by that query using Excel, but the list was too long to crunch. Any help? I know this is a basic, but I am not a database person... What would the SQL code look like to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `JOIN` instead of `UNION` to achieve what you want.

Something like that should work:

```
SELECT SUB.ID, MASTER.CODE
FROM SUB
JOIN MASTER
ON SUB.ID = MASTER.ID
```

In general, `JOIN` allows you to match some rows from one table to the rows from other table according to the value(s) in these rows (think of it as "gluing" rows together along the vertical axis to form longer rows), while what `UNION` does is just adding all rows from one table below other table (i.e. appends one table to the end of other table along the horizontal axis).